# Setup dynamic upstream with nginx

Tags: nginx, load-balancing, geo

Suppose that i have to upstream source

```
upstream first {
}

upstream second {
}
```

And then in `server` block

```
map $geoip_country_code $is_china {
    default no;
    CN yes;
}
```

What I would like to achieve is if `$is_china`, use a different upstream

```
proxy_pass http://$preferred_host/;
```

I can't figure how to do this with nginx.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`map` might be just sufficient. Have you tried the following?

```
map $geoip_country_code $preferred_host {
    default first;
    CN      second;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I just learnt about `map` too. I will try this as it look cleaner than the above.

Comment: np. One good thing about `map` is that you can add more key value pairs easily.

Answer (score 1):

Turn out I can use `if` in nginx

```
set $preferred_host http://first;
if ($is_china) {
    set $preferred_host http://second;
}

location / {
    proxy_pass $preferred_host/;
    ...
}
```